# How to change default cell/column content after a responsive DataTables table collapses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [Bootstrap 4, DataTables and the Responsive extension](https://datatables.net/download/#bs4/dt-1.10.16/r-2.2.0) to create a responsive table.
For one column I define default content, i.e. a default HTML element, with `defaultContent`.
I also use the `createdRow` callback to change that default content after a row is inserted (e.g. adding a listener to that HTML element etc).

My problem is that if I shrink the window and the table rows collapse, the default column value reverts to its original value -- it's like `createdRow` was never called.
If I expand the window again, the new default values are shown again.

Normal table:

[image]

Collapsed (note the old default values for the "Buttons" column):

[image]

I'm guessing that, after the rows collapse, some new cells are created and that's why `createdRow` is never called.

How do I change the default column values for collapsed cells?

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/7wa9983s/